# Consistent estimator of the mean

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm trying to figure out whether

$ (\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i) $ + 15

and

$ \frac{1}{n}\sum_ {i=1}^n( X_i +15)$

are consistent estimators of the mean.

---

I'm using Chebyshev's inequality to solve this and want to find the variance of the two equations above.

I have that the variance of the first is equal to var($\overline{X}$) but I'm having trouble with the variance of the second.

My work so far is:

$ \frac{1}{n^2}$Var($\sum_{i=1}(X_i +15)$)

What's confusing me is that I end up getting the same answer for both (and that they both simplify to 0 after I take the limit to infinity) and I thought that wouldn't be the case.

Comment: Consistent estimators converge to true value $E(X)$ in probability. Your estimators (identical) converge to $E(X)+15$ in probability, hence they are not consistent.

Comment: Can you write an answer to this question using Chebyshev's inequality? It converges to 0 when I solved it, but perhaps I'm making a mistake.

Comment: You would use Chevyshev's inequality to show consistency only AFTER you show that $E(estimator)\to E(X)$. The latter doesn't hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When manipulating sums we have the following rules

- $\sum_{i=m}^n(a_i+b_i) = \left(\sum_{i=m}^na_i\right) + \left(\sum_{i=m}^nb_i\right)$
- If $b_i = b$ is a constant then $\sum_{i=m}^nb_i = \sum_{i=m}^n b = (n-m+1)b$.

Using the rules above we find that

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i+15) = \frac{1}{n}\left(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right) + \frac{1}{n}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n15\right) =  \frac{1}{n}\left(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right) + 15$$

so your two expression are in fact identical and it's therefore no surprise that you get the same result.

---

A [consistent estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_estimator) of a parameter is an estimator that converges in probabillity to the true value of the parameter. For your estimatator $Y_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i + 15$ we have

$$\text{p}\lim_{n\to\infty} Y_n = E[X] + 15 \not= E[X]$$

so this is not a consistent estimator of the mean (i.e. of $E[X]$).

Comment: Are they also consistent estimators of the mean though?